# convert char to string in loop in java and then Set it to JtextField

Tags: java

```
public void auto() {  
    String x = jTextField1.getText().toUpperCase();  
    String[] myName = x.split(" ");  
    for (int i = 0; i < myName.length; i++) {  
        String s = myName[i];  
        System.out.print(s.charAt(0));  
    }   
}
```

I just want to get all the first letter of every word and save it to another Text Field how to do it.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Your code looks like it's already extracting the first letter from each word (as separated by spaces). What specifically is causing you trouble?

Comment: I just wants to get value from a text field and get every words 1st letter and then save it to another  text field

Comment: you can use StringBuilder to append s.charAt(0) and use this StringBuilder to show result on TextField. You can consider Regex also to solve this simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already extracts the first letter of each word. For the rest of you question it's quite simple. Put the letters into a variable and set the text of a different textfield.

```
public void auto() {  
    String result = "";
    String x = jTextField1.getText().toUpperCase();  
    String[] myName = x.split(" ");  
    for (int i = 0; i < myName.length; i++) {  
        String s = myName[i];
        result += s.charAt(0);
    }
    jDifferentTextField.setText(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i don't think like that

Comment: No problem! If this is the correct solution for you problem, please mark this answer as correct for any future users to see

Comment: I will add that for assembling a string sequence in a loop, it's more efficient to use a `StringBuilder`. (Though for small input strings there won't be much performance cost.)